# delete and unlike image in php oops

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to delete image from database in php oops. I created this class. It delete data from data base but not unlike function is not working some one. Plz help me.

```
<!-- session start --> 
 <?php 
if (($session->logged_in) && ($session->isAdmin())) {


}
 else{
header("Location: index.php");

}
?>
<!-- session end here -->

 <?php

 $obj=new Crud("localhost","root","","3g");
 class Crud{
    public $mysqli;

public $data;

public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$db_name){

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";

    exit;

    }
    /*else{
        echo"Your Database successfully connected"; 
    }*/

}

public function __destruct(){
    $this->mysqli->close(); 
}





 public function read(){

    $query="SELECT * FROM fashion";

    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);

    $num_result=$result->num_rows;


    if($num_result>0){
        while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){

            $this->data[]=$rows;

            //print_r($rows);


        }

        return $this->data;
    }

 }


 public function delete($id){

 $sql=mysql_query("select * from fashion where where id='$id'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

unlink("fashion/$row[thumbnail_image]");


    $query="DELETE FROM fashion WHERE id='$id'";

    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted");

    if($result){
        header('location:fashion.php'); 
    }


}




 }

 ?>
```

I have tried soo many codes and try some different ways but the problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to unlink a file named "$row[thumbnail_image]" try changing

```
unlink("fashion/$row[thumbnail_image]");
```

to

```
unlink("fashion/" . $row["thumbnail_image"]);
```

Comment: still not deleting the image from folder i have try too  if i write the name of the specific image then it delete the image but from database its not working

Comment: what are the contents of $row["thumbnail_image"] ?

Comment: i m saving an image to data base and then fatch the name of that image to unlike that image

Comment: data base contain (id)(original_image)(thumbnail_image) i m only want to delete thumbnail_image from folder

Comment: i think image name is not fatching here unlink("fashion/" . $row["thumbnail_image"]); and its not showing me any error etc